# Pandas .agg() dropping columns (lambda function)

Tags: pandas, join, lambda, group-by, aggregate

I have a df (df.shape = (14762, 35)).

```
Number    Day        Colour   City ...
123       Monday     Red      London ...
234       Monday     Blue     Paris ...
234       Wednesday  Yellow   Paris ... 
345       Tuesday    Green    Berlin ...
```

I am trying to groupby and aggregate the df to produce

```
Number    Day                Colour        City ...
123       Monday             Red           London ...
234       Monday, Wednesday  Blue, Yellow  Paris ...
345       Tuesday            Green         Berlin ...
```

I'm using

```
df.groupby('Number').agg(lambda s: ', '.join({*s}))
```

However, my new df has a shape (5435, 22). The problem is in the aggregate step lambda function. The groupby step works fine. Just wondering why the .agg or .join might drop certain columns. I've read about nuisance columns during groupby, but I don't think that is the problem.

I've printed the `.dtypes` and the columns being dropped are `object`, `int64` and `float64`.

I'm using Python 3.6.9 and pandas 0.25.3.

Comment: What version of pandas, what version of python? Also, in the original dataframe - what is the `dtype` of the columns being dropped?

Comment: Python 3.6.9 and Pandas 0.25.3. The columns being dropped are objects, float64s int64s. Some of the objects are dictionaries within {} curly brackets as the file is read in from a .json, but not all of them.

Comment: I would expect `float64` and `int64` to be dropped as the `join` function will raise a `TypeError`. You can fix that by changing the aggregating function to `lambda x: ', '.join([str(i) for i in x])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect `float64` and `int64` to be dropped as the `join` function will raise a `TypeError`. You might be facing the same problem, i.e. inability to use the `join` on other `object` columns also.

You can fix that by changing the aggregating function to -

`lambda x: ', '.join([str(i) for i in x])`

Comment: That seems to have worked, thanks. I didn't realise that join struggled with `float64` and `int64`types. The code run fine without raising an error, strange...

Comment: Great! Yes, `join` does struggle with non-string formats. For example, ', '.join([1, 2, 3]) will raise a `TypeError`- but I am not sure if this behaviour of *failing silently* is by design in pandas